# Unable to start the environment. To retry, refresh the browser or restart by selecting Actions, Restart AWS CloudShell

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am unable to use aws cloud shell. I operate in the supported region (Ireleand) and my user has the right permissions (AWSCloudShellFullAccess).

```
{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Action": [ "cloudshell:*" ], "Effect": "Allow", "Resource": "*" } ] }
```

Why is it disabled?

I tried to follow this guide. But the advice there doesnt work.
[AWS cloudshell troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html)

Comment: A typical problem with cloud services and authentication is, that your os time must be correct. Is your system time correct and not more than 1 minute from real time apart? do you use time servers for synchronizing your system time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i was able to resolve this issue. Few things to try to create CloudShell environment:

- Time Synchronization: Make sure Your machine time is accurate. It means its correct based on world time. did you try from another machine to see if its working there? may be any time sync related issue?
- Check in different regions..
- check AWSCloudShellFullAccess policy to ensure it has below JSON data.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudshell:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Check in different browser to see if it works in different browser or not. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html
- Did you deleted cloudshell home directory or something? Try after resetting home directory. But it can DELETE all your data exists in home directory. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/vm-specs.html#deleting-home-directory
- check if any DENY policy created for it. remove that.
- It is possible your account is not 100% verified. Try this: Create a CloudFront distribution if you get the below error it confirms your account is unverified or if you can create 2 distributions and can't create the 3rd one.

> Your account must be verified before you can add new CloudFront
> resources. To verify your account, please contact AWS Support
> (https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/ ) and include this
> error message.

Click the support link

1. Navigate to:
   Support / New case / Service limit increase
2. Limit type:
   CloudFront Distributions
3. In Requests select:
   Limit: Web Distributions per Account
   New limit value: <TYPE_YOUR_NEW_VALUE_HERE>

MY CASE: In my case, I had 2 distributions, wanted to create 3rd, but couldn't. So I have put as <TYPE_YOUR_NEW_VALUE_HERE> a number 10.

Note: If nothing works choose last option as your last resort to confirm your account is verified.

Answer (score 0):

In case you tried everything mentioned in other solutions and issue still persists (that's how it was for me;), you can create a free support ticket:

Go to [AWS Support Portal](https://support.console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/)
Click on Create Case > Account and billing > Service: "Account" | Category: "Other Account Issues" | Severity: "General question"

AWS Support team will quickly respond(even on weekends :). You can expect the case to be solved within 12 to 24 hours.

[image: Screenshot of AWS Support Request]